# How to copy the current value of a `set` option into the clipboard?

Tags: vimrc, cut-copy-paste, options, os-clipboard

I sometimes need to copy the current value of a `set` option, e.g. `set statusline`, into the clipboard (`+`) to paste its value here.

I know how to show the current value of a `set` option, e.g. `set statusline?`, but how can I copy that value to the clipboard (`+`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like this

```
let @+ = &statusline
```

Or like this

```
call setreg("+", getbufvar("%", "&statusline"))
```

Or even like this...

```
if has("nvim")
  call provider#clipboard#Call("set", [[matchstr(execute("set statusline"), "=\@=.*"], "v", "+"])
endif
```